# Regular Expression Usage in Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

Here I want to copy some substring from database column and append it at the end of column.

E.g.

Data in column looks like:

```
 string data -id pattern -xyz test some data
```

This should be replaced like this

```
 string data -id pattern -xyz test some data -c test.pattern.pl
```

You can see that I want to copy string after `-id` and before `-xyz` and append it at the end betwenn test and pl

If some column is

```
string data -id john -xyz test some data
```

Then the replaced value should be

```
string data -id john -xyz test some data -c test.john.pl
```

I tried using `REGEXP_REPLACE`/`REGEXP_SUBSTR` but not able to resolve it.

Comment: So what regex are you using which doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

In 11g, you could use [`regexp_substr`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions150.htm#i1239858) to get the pattern directly:

```
select txt, regexp_substr(txt, '-id ([^ ]*)', 1, 1, '', '1')
  from (select 'string data -id john -xyz test some data' txt from dual)

TXT                                        REG
string data -id john -xyz test some data   john
```

Before 11g, you could use a combination of `regexp_substr` and `substr`:

```
select txt, 
       substr(regexp_substr(txt, '-id [^ ]*'), 4) sub
  from (select 'string data -id john -xyz test some data' txt from dual)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select p,
       p || regexp_replace(p, '(.*-id )(.*)( -xyz.*)', ' -c test.\2.pl') np
  from t
```

(`t` is your table and `p` is the column name)

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b8315/1) is a fiddle